# Inheriting Required XML Attributes from Custom Theme

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-widget

### The Problem:

I have several TextViews that share a large number of identical attributes. I'd like to apply the following style to all the TextViews.

```
<!-- TextView -->
<style name="fieldLabel" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">0.7</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

But for some reason, when I apply this style as an activity-wide theme I get this error:

```
09-08 15:57:17.034: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5269): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #38: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

This is *only* happens when I try to apply this style as a theme. Because, when I add

```
style="@style/fieldLabel"
```

individually to every TextView's attributes it works as expected, so the error is coming from trying to apply this theme to the *entire activity.*

---

### The Code:

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="CustomActivityStyle" parent="android:Theme"> <!--This is theme I am trying to apply -->
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/fieldLabel</item>
</style>

<!-- TextView -->
<style name="fieldLabel" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">0.7</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

**myactivity.xml:**

```
<!-- This is an example of one of the TextViews -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_label"
    android:text="@string/name_label"
/>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<!-- Implementing the theme in the Manifest -->
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActivityStyle"
    android:label="@string/my_title">
</activity>
```

There is another thread on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642597/must-supply-a-layout-height-but-its-in-my-style-resources), but I decided to ask a new question instead of reviving the old one.

**To Summarize:**

I do know that I could easily make this work by simply adding the layout_width and layout_height attributes, *or* by explicitly adding the style="@style/fieldLabel" to each TextView. But the point of this question is more to improve my (and hopefully others) coding conventions, as well as making the code itself more readable and reusable.

I am actually very surprised that no one has come across this issue before, and that this is not more of a standard way of formatting.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is usually a layout related exception, can you post the full stacktrace and layout file.

Comment: @Dan I've edited my original question to include the full stack trace and the entire layout file. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score -1):

This is the problem:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #20: You
>   must supply a layout_width attribute.

Your TextView id name_label, requires a `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` attribute.

Comment: Yes, but I am supplying both a layout_height and a layout_width using a custom theme that should apply to all the textviews in the activity. So the question is, why are they not inheriting those fields correctly?

Comment: I've never seen anyone apply a height and width via style. Does each TextView need its own style attribute?

Comment: If I explicitly add the style attribute to each TextView it will work, but I was hoping to avoid that by adding the style to the entire Activity using the android:theme attribute in the manifest. I don't see any reason why this should not work, thus my original question. Thanks for helping by the way!