# layout_width and layout_height is not applying to edittext from the theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

Below i have added `EditText` style in theme. I have added width and height also. So i removed `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` from my `edittext` view. But it is saying error. If i add width and height it is working fine. What is the difference. Is theme is not applying to my edittext view?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/custom_EditTextStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="custom_EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
         <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittextbox</item>
         <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
         <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
         <item name="android:layout_height">48dp</item>
    </style>
```

My editText view

```
 <EditText android:hint="Username" />
```

Comment: where is your style attribute? <EditText style= "@style/custom_EditTextStyle" android:hint="Username" />

Comment: Is it a lint or compilation error?

Answer (score 6):

Your `styles.xml` must contain

`<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">` at the top.

If this file was auto-generated or you made this file yourself, this attribute is sometimes forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the style to the `EditText`:

```
 <EditText android:hint="Username"
  style="@style/custom_EditTextStyle" />
```

Edit: based on your comment I think this is what you want:

```
<EditText android:hint="Username"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: This is style. but i need from theme without applying the style.

Comment: But i already added height and width in the above style. Why again you added in your updated code? isnt it duplicate?

Comment: If you want don't want to apply style then you need to do the second option because you aren't applying the style therefore you are not applying the height and width attributes to the EditText.

Comment: <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittextbox</item>
<item name="android:singleLine">true</item> already there. These two are applying without adding style to editText. But why width and height are not applying?