# Why is it not possible to set layout_height and layout_width for toolbar in theme with toolbarStyle?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

Challenge: I am trying to set layout_height and layout_width for toolbar through a default toolbar theme like so:

within my theme I have:

```
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Toolbar</item>
```

and the Toolbar style:

```
<style name="Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorBackground</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextColor">@color/colorTextToolbar</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

Problem: `layout_height` and `layout_width` is not being taken from my theme, when I delete `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` from my Toolbar, the toolbar completely disappears with an error saying  these properties are missing. Though `android:background` and `android:titleTextColor` are being taken from my theme actually.

What I tried: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840635/layout-width-and-layout-height-is-not-applying-to-edittext-from-the-theme) I read I would have to add `<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">` at the top. This had no effect actually and already have `<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">` at the top.

Do you have any idea why this is not working? Might this be due to how the inflater takes attributes from the precedence of styling?

Update: it seems as if toolbarStyle doesnt allow to set height and width of toolbars. I guess that this might be defined somewhere within the android docs, though I can´t find out where exactly. When I click on toolbar object I find

```
public Toolbar(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.toolbarStyle);
}
```

as Constructur, so it takes `R.attr.toolbarStyleR.attr.toolbarStyle` as argument and when I look at toolbarStyle attribute I can only see
`<attr format="reference" name="toolbarStyle"/>`, which doesnt give me a clue what "toolbarStyle" really sets. Is there a way to find this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the style to the `Toolbar`:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/Toolbar"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: but isn´t this contradictory to the concept of theme? Then I would prefer to separate style for toolbar and the theme style for my toolbar.

Comment: How would that affect your theme? idk if i understood you correctly

Comment: Keep in mind that toolbarStyle does not add a width and height which are mandatory for every view.

Comment: I actually thought it would be possible to set height and width through toolbarStyle. So it seems as if the question comes down to, whether which attributes are allowed to set within toolbarStyle and which not. So I updated the question due this discussion

Comment: You can still use the Toolbar style like I said *and* use the theme as usual with no conflicts.

Comment: Seems like a good workaround, but I still don´t know why android doenst allow to set the properties through theme.