# Android app not running on HTC devices

Tags: android, eclipse, htc-android

My android app work on my samsung galaxy 2, and many others samsung devices. Then my friend tried HTC, installed correctly but when i turn on this app after 1 sec of white screen it turns off. Looks like program dont work same way on HTC. This happen on every HTC i tried. Any reasons what can cause this ?

> Permissions needed : GPS, network localization and read external
>
> storage minSDKv.: 8
>
> targetSDKv.: 16
>
> ProjectBuildTarget: 21(i tried lower still no working)

(installed correctly so i think its not API problem)

Comment: Can you post what response you get in the logcat when you are executing the app on a HTC device ?

Comment: i dont have HTC - and cant find HTC virtual device settings. Only 2 friends with HTC phone 300, 50 km away installed apk file and they said its not working

Comment: Try using GenyMotion Emulator, in which you can download a HTC device VM and then test your app on your system itself.

Comment: Thanks, perfect emulator. error - style contains key with bad entry. Problems with style user3344236 was right,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check again your @style declarations. Sometimes the preinstalled theme in some distributions simple don't allow basic things like translucent bar etc.

Comment: in styles :
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
_______________________________________________________________
manifest:
android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"

Comment: yes, again, check your friend htc theme. Should be the bone for your lesson. You don't know how producers (htc) can spoil over your work "just because we embed a theme" inside our devices. For now, just comment your *light theme reference. It will work.

Comment: do not say they have android 4.x, just take over the theme element.

Comment: i didnt defined this theme in all values foldes. Waiting till friendc come online to test it but think this will fix it. Found this when start focus on styles.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947720/android-theme-not-being-set

Comment: i still cant get it What should i have in styles.xml ? delete all my custom styles but still error style contains key with bad entry

Answer (score 0):

OLD: 
style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"

NEW:

style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme"