# AndroidManifest - Set theme for activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I am really frustrated right now and read a ton - maybe you can help me out.
Why is Android Studio still showing me "Main2Activity" with the titlebar?

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.martin.myapplication">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"></activity>
</application>
```

I know it is really a small issue but I am unable to figure it out...

Sources I used:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html

[Android theme not being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947720/android-theme-not-being-set)

[Apply a theme to an activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125163/apply-a-theme-to-an-activity-in-android/19125267)

**EDIT**
Current State:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm4pz.png)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Is working but disables the ActionBar for every Activity!

*Goal: activity_main2 should not have an ActionBar.*

**SOLVED** It is just a bug from Android Studio. In the Preview it won't disable the AppBar but as soon as you play the App on your phones it works!

Comment: Does your XML layout have a Toolbar?

Comment: Tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25365193/2308683

Comment: Yes the goal is that my layout will have a toolbar. At the moment to put it in a simple case: I got 2 activitys. One of them will keep the "default" bar and the other one will get a toolbar. Therefore Fullscreen is no option for me sry

Comment: My point is that you're still seeing the bar because the Activity layout told it to load one, even though the theme doesn't have one

Comment: Sorry, I am confused now: Yes, the default is that my App hat an AppBar. but giving an activity another theme in the Manifest doesn't change anything. And I don't know why...

Comment: `<Toolbar>` in the XML layout will always be displayed. Regardless of the theme settings.  If you also use a theme with a ActionBar, you'll get two bars.

Comment: Can you just add the layout of both activities to the question? Also a screenshot of both? And highlight the difference you want

Comment: My goal is to have an activity without anything. By using 
 `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`
it is working but for every activity. I simply want this for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Hide the Action Bar add the below code in Values/Styles

```
<style name="CustomActivityThemeNoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then in your AndroidManifest.xml file add the below code in the required activity:

```
<activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActivityThemeNoTitle"></activity>
```

Alternatively, you can call `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in the onCreate method for your activity. For example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ty but is it possible to just use XML?

Comment: @TakIncur I have modified my answer to include the XML solution as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: Probably should use an AppCompat theme instead of Holo

Comment: I have changed to use Theme.Light, which is what the OP originally had.

Comment: Or that, if not using AppCompatActivity

Comment: I am currently trying your answer. I will report asap. TY for you efford this far :)

Comment: Sry that it took this long. Sorry your solution did not work. Neither in the Studio nor on my Smartphone. I honestly did the same you suggested already before but it really is not showing any changes :/ btw I am using KitKat 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style name="generalnotitle" parent="general">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This isn't placed in the manifest... Also the NoTitleBar theme does this already

Comment: Sry this isn't helping me out.