# Android theme doesn't apply fully to a device

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I have created a custom theme for my Android application. In the designer and several real test devices they all show correctly, but a particular device doesn't seem to apply parts of the theme correctly. It looks like for some reason anything inactive/disabled uses the styling for the opposite state. Example: [image: screenshot]
The blue button is disabled, and the text in the input control is actually a hint, but they aren't grayed out despite that on the problematic device.

The theme itself didn't change much from the base theme:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@android:color/background_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
</style>
```

The device runs Android 6.0, the app targets API level >= 19. Another test device from a different manufacturer with the same Android version works correctly.

I have tried a few proposed solutions, like copying the theme into `values-v11` and `values-v14` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/13443946/4429472, but none of them fixed the problem.

EDIT: the phone in question is Leagoo M8, with Freeme OS.

Comment: can you please provide the information about that specific device.

Comment: Please, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

in your res>value>colours.xml

add this

```
    <color name="colorForeground">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="holo_blue_bright">#ff00ddff</color>
    <color name="bright_foreground_light_disabled">#80000000</color>
    <color name="bright_foreground_light">#ff000000</color>
```

create a selecter in your drawable folder with name selector_text.xml past this code

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/bright_foreground_light_disabled"/>
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:color="@color/bright_foreground_light"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/bright_foreground_light"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/bright_foreground_light"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/bright_foreground_light"/>
    <item android:color="@color/bright_foreground_light"/> <!-- not selected -->

</selector>
```

update your style with this also rename the style AppTheme_custom and do change in manifest and where ever you used this theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme_custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/colorForeground</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@drawable/selector_text</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/holo_blue_bright</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Can you clarify why and how does it fix the issue?

Comment: you are using default value of OS so , in case of custom  OS values may override . so it wil be better to use your own value of resources.

Comment: have you change the AppTheme  name to AppTheme_custom at it's usage also.

Comment: Yes, I did rename the theme, even tho it isn't clear to me why would that matter.

Comment: to avoid conflicts  with OS value , if it is.
Just Try one more thing change the TextView in AppCompatTextView .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178516/discussion-between-zzzombo-and-r7g).